# Audit failed but should be considered as duplicate

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Today I just failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9713038) (question asked 30 days ago) I marked as duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261703/set-css-border-to-end-in-a-90-instead-of-a-45-degree-angle) (asked four years ago). Even a comment on the audit question was linking to this question.

I was surprised to know that it was in fact an audit, so I first thought of going to the question and flag it as duplicate  so it'll no longer be an audit. Though the answers on this question (that is clearly a duplicate) are better than the 4-years old question.

My question is, what should be done in that kind of case? Should I flag the old question as duplicate of the new one? And what can be done about the audit? I find it a bit confusing.

Comment: The general advice is if the new question, and its answers, are better than the old, mark the old as a dupe of the new. Basically, we want the open question to be the best one/the one with the better answers. Time should only come into play if they're of a comparable quality on all fronts. As for the audit part, I feel like there was a question recently about failing an audit by flagging as a dupe. Let me see if I can find it and see if it would help in your situation.